# AJAX Complete Handler not beeing fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events

After some hard work on the backend of my Web Application I noticed that the GetMeasure Request takes up to 10 seconds to finish. I decided to apply an overlay so a potential user won't get confused because nothing happens on the screen. No matter if the request is successfull or not the overlay should get removed after the call - so using the complete handler should be the best choice - at least I thought. I really don't get why but in opposite to the success handler the complete handler won't get called.

AJAX Request:

```
$_loadingCircle = $('<img id="loading" src="http://www.obergurgl.com/_images/layout/loading.gif"/>');
PopulateOverlay($_loadingCircle);
$.ajax({
    url: 'CoDTracker/Home/GetMeasures',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "html",
    data: {
        buID: buid,
        aID: aid,
        lID: lid
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#measures').html(data);
    },
    complete: function () {
        $_overlay.remove();
    }
});
```

The request ends with status 200 (successfull) but the overlay won't get removed. I'm sure that the request completed because my measures got filled into the page while the circle spins as crazy instead of disappearing.

Am I doing something wrong?

Edit:

Overlay-definition

```
function PopulateOverlay($content) {
    $_overlay = $('<div class="overlay">');
    $content.appendTo($_overlay);
    $_overlay.appendTo('body');
}
```

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: Please show us how `$_overlay` is defined, because from the example above, this variable (i.e. object) isn't defined anywhere. Just because the overlay isn't being hidden, doesn't mean the `complete:` doesn't fire. In fact, I think your problem is with the `$_overlay`. You could test this by adding `console.log('Hello World!');` in the `complete: function() {     }`

Comment: Is all these code in a function, and you'd call that function many times?

Comment: I think you are redfining `$_overlay` while ajax request is running, maybe by calling `PopulateOverlay()` more than once. Your question is missing relevant context for sure

Answer (score 1):

Your `$_overlay` is defined incorrectly.
Please use:

```
$_overlay = $('div.overlay');
```

And please refer to jQuery Selectors for more information:
https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
The way to select a div with a particular class, is not to copy the entire `<div class="">`, but rather as I did in the example above.

EDIT: in fact, if you make this change, your PopulateOverlay will no longer work, so you should rather just select it without assigning it to a variable:

```
complete: function () {
    $('div.overlay').remove();
}
```

Comment: It looks like OP wants to define a new div, not targeting any already existing in DOM

Comment: Actually OP is trying to do both. The div is created with the PopulateOverlay function. It is then removed once the AJAX request completes. If I were to do something like this myself, I would already put the `<div class="overlay">` in my HTML, but just hidden, and then make it visible when the AJAX request starts, and hide it again when the AJAX request completes.

Comment: Ya, toggling the display of a `div` would be clever indeed

Answer (score 1):

Because overlay is appended in the DOM, you should remove it with `.class`:

```
complete: function () {
    $('.overlay').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if there's no error, and that's all your code, it should work fine.
Let's try to make an example, with a `mimic` function to mimic the behavior of ajax complete, we can write it like:

```js
var $_overlay = null;    // We assume you define it somewhere, and it's visible to all your functions.

function PopulateOverlay($content) {
    $_overlay = $('<div class="overlay">');
    $content.appendTo($_overlay);
    $_overlay.appendTo('body');
}

// See this as an ajax call with 2 sec delay.
function mimic(cb) { 
 setTimeout(cb, 2000);
}

function theWorks() {
    $someEle = $('<div class="example">example</div>');
    PopulateOverlay($someEle);
    mimic(function() {
     $_overlay.remove();
    });
}

$(function() {
  theWorks();
});
```

```css
.overlay {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}

.example {
  color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So I guess, that your codes, is inside another function, and you may call it many times, let's make a button, and click to trigger it:

```js
var $_overlay = null;    // We assume you define it somewhere, and it's visible to all your functions.

function PopulateOverlay($content) {
    $_overlay = $('<div class="overlay">');
    $content.appendTo($_overlay);
    $_overlay.appendTo('body');
}

// See this as an ajax call with 2 sec delay.
function mimic(cb) { 
 setTimeout(cb, 2000);
}

function theWorks() {
    $someEle = $('<div class="example">example</div>');
    PopulateOverlay($someEle);
    mimic(function() {
      debugger;
     $_overlay.remove();
    });
}

$(function() {
  $('#click').on('click', theWorks);
});
```

```css
.overlay {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}

.example {
  color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="click">Click</button>
```

Now, if click the button before the previous pop out disappear, some popouts last forever.

Why? Because when you click again, your `$_overlay` will be assign to a newly created element, which means you lost the reference to the previous pop out, and when later the remove works takes action, it only remove the newest one, and all the following removes, are about to remove something that is not on the page, so you won't see effects, and older popouts remains.

We could fix it, by catch the current element in another variable when you're executing your codes. This would work if you expect many pop outs.

```js
var $_overlay = null;    // We assume you define it somewhere, and it's visible to all your functions.

function PopulateOverlay($content) {
    $_overlay = $('<div class="overlay">');
    $content.appendTo($_overlay);
    $_overlay.appendTo('body');
}

// See this as an ajax call with 2 sec delay.
function mimic(cb) { 
 setTimeout(cb, 2000);
}

function theWorks() {
    $someEle = $('<div class="example">example</div>');
    PopulateOverlay($someEle);
    
    // Cache the current overlay, or simply move $_overlay here, if no other using it.
    var $_curOverlay = $_overlay;
    
    mimic(function() {
     $_curOverlay.remove();
    });
}

$(function() {
  $('#click').on('click', theWorks);
});
```

```css
.overlay {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}

.example {
  color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="click">Click</button>
```

Or as what [Laurens Swart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4065947/laurens-swart) suggest, simply toggle the state if you only need one pop out at a time.

```js
var $_overlay = $('.overlay');

function PopulateOverlay($content) {
    $_overlay
      .empty()                // Clear previous
      .append($content)  // Append the content
      .show();                // Make it visible.
}

// See this as an ajax call with 2 sec delay.
function mimic(cb) { 
 setTimeout(cb, 2000);
}

function theWorks() {
    $someEle = $('<div class="example">example</div>');
    PopulateOverlay($someEle);   
    mimic(function() {
     $_overlay.hide();  // Instead of remove, we make it hide, so we can reuse it later.
    });
}

$(function() {
  $('#click').on('click', theWorks);
});
```

```css
.overlay {
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}

.example {
  color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="click">Click</button>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```